# GruntJS erro na instalação do plugin usando Vagrant

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js, grunt

Tento instalar o puglin

> npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev

no meu projeto usando vagrant e dá erro de permissão segue abaixo :

```
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-61-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-contrib-     uglify" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.4d84521811f489f4938c27a69db45fbf
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26

npm ERR! ETXTBSY, rename 'npm-debug.log.4d84521811f489f4938c27a69db45fbf'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
npm ERR!     /vagrant/angular-grunt/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce tem que rodar o comando como root ou usar sudo:

```
sudo npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
```

Comment: já utiizo o SUDO e mesmo assim não funciona

Comment: Qual erro você tem quando utiliza o sudo?

Comment: o mesmo que reportei :|

Comment: Voce tentou como usuario root? E' estranho voce ter o mesmo erro com sudo....

Comment: eu não sei se é pq to usando vagrant